# Error waveOutOpen when play wav more times [delphi]

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

I found code from internet, First i play wave file and no problem, then i play wav more times and appear error at times 48. I know error from waveOutOpen function.

This is my code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses MMSystem;

{$R *.dfm}


var

  buf: Array of byte;
  wh: TWaveHdr;
  hOut: HWAVEOUT;
  fmt: TWaveFormatEx;
  count: integer;


function GetWaveFmtData(path: string; var fmt: TWaveFormatEx ): Boolean;
var
  hFile: HMMIO;
  ckiRIFF,ckiFmt,ckiData: TMMCKInfo;
begin
  Result := False;
  hFile := mmioOpen(PChar(path), nil, MMIO_READ);
  if hFile = 0 then Exit;

  ZeroMemory(@ckiRIFF, SizeOf(TMMCKInfo));
  ZeroMemory(@ckiFmt, SizeOf(TMMCKInfo));
  ZeroMemory(@ckiData, SizeOf(TMMCKInfo));

  ckiRIFF.fccType := mmioStringToFOURCC('WAVE', 0);
  ckiFmt.ckid := mmioStringToFOURCC('fmt', 0);
  ckiData.ckid := mmioStringToFOURCC('data', 0);

  ZeroMemory(@fmt, SizeOf(TWaveFormatEx));

  mmioDescend(hFile, @ckiRIFF, nil, MMIO_FINDRIFF);

  if (ckiRIFF.ckid = FOURCC_RIFF) and (ckiRIFF.fccType = mmioStringToFOURCC('WAVE',0)) and
  (mmioDescend(hFile, @ckiFmt, @ckiRIFF, MMIO_FINDCHUNK) = MMSYSERR_NOERROR) and
  (mmioRead(hFile, @fmt, ckiFmt.cksize) = ckiFmt.cksize) and
  (mmioAscend(hFile, @ckiFmt, 0) = MMSYSERR_NOERROR) and
  (mmioDescend(hFile, @ckiData, @ckiRIFF, MMIO_FINDCHUNK) = MMSYSERR_NOERROR) then
  begin
  SetLength(buf, ckiData.cksize);
  Result := (mmioRead(hFile, PAnsiChar(buf), ckiData.cksize) = ckiData.cksize);
  end;

  mmioClose(hFile, 0);
end;


Procedure CallBack(
  hwo :HWAVEOUT;
  uMsg :UINT ;
  dwInstance :DWORD;
  dwParam1 :DWORD;
  dwParam2 :DWORD
);stdcall;
begin
  {Need check the message here but for now lets just make sure
   that we get called }
  ShowMessage('WaveOut');
end;



procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  path = 'fire.wav';

begin

  GetWaveFmtData(path, fmt);

  wh.lpData := PAnsiChar(buf);
  wh.dwBufferLength := Length(buf);
  wh.dwBytesRecorded := 0;
  wh.dwUser := 0;
  wh.dwFlags := 0;
  wh.dwLoops := 1;
  wh.lpNext := nil;
  wh.reserved := 0;

  //waveOutClose(hOut);

  if waveOutOpen(@hOut, WAVE_MAPPER, @fmt, DWORD(@CallBack),
  Handle,WAVE_MAPPED and CALLBACK_FUNCTION) = MMSYSERR_NOERROR then
  begin
    count:=count+1;
    Edit1.Text:=IntToStr(count);
  end;

  waveOutPrepareHeader(hOut, @wh, SizeOf(TWaveHdr));
  waveOutWrite(hOut, @wh, SizeOf(TWaveHdr));

end;

end.
```

By the way, CallBack function don't work, please any one help me!
Here is [Full code.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/38r586md8u32s9d/wavout+test.rar)
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Are you saying you get error 42 from the wave functions? Use [`waveOutGetErrorText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert the error code into a string.

Comment: I want to say when play audio 48 times it'll be disabled and no sound. While i want play sound forever until i want close it.

Comment: I have some experience with playing wav files and call back is not reliable. I have had callback working on some machines and not others and working one the same machine sometimes and not others. In the end I had to resort to the safety first method of reading the header, seeing how long it should play for, and firing a timer after a slightly longer period to ensure the file was closed. Horrible and frustrating but 100% reliable.

Comment: Thank you. So to play wav with wavout not effect for me, because a application maybe has multi audio are played at same time and more. example: games applications. My purpose is play multi audio from stream or array at same time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not reasonable to expect to be able to play infinitely many messages at the same time. presumably each message is MP3 or MP4, so although these are quicker to decode than encode they will not be infinitely quick. Then the resultant wave samples must be added together, ensuring that there is no resultant numeric overflow which would cause severe distortion at worst or clipping at best. This all takes time. There are also the memory considerations but time is more likely to be a factor. So the driver will probably limit the number of sounds it can play at any one time in order to be able to play the sounds quickly enough and without distortion. If it doesn't then there may well be overflow issues.

Most audio is traditionally 24 bit stereo (48 bits), so a driver based on 64 bit technology is likely to start experiencing overflow problems after merging, best case, about 40 samples. 32 bit based drivers will likely experience problems much sooner.

Comment: Thanks Dsm. At the moment i use DSpack component instead of wavout. Everything are good for me, however this component seem can not play audio from Memorystream.